# how to deploy react app with github gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, web-deployment

I have created react application without using boilerplate create-react-app. I want to deploy it with git hub. Can I deploy it ? if yes, can anyone suggest steps ?

Comment: See https://nataliecardot.medium.com/easily-deploy-a-create-react-app-project-to-github-pages-280529adb086

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `gh-pages` package installed and you know how to deploy a `index.html` for example, add this in your `package.json` scripts:

```
scripts: {
    ...,
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

Then run `npm run deploy`.

Take a look at this in depth article about it, if you get stuck, or leave some comments to this answer

https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f

Comment: I am getting the error ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Other\projects\TreeStructure\build' when i tried this way.

Comment: `gh-pages -d build` in this command, `build` should be the name of the folder where react app is built, it could be `/dist` or `/build`. Try running `npm run build` and seeing which new folder appears. if it is `dist` try making it `gh-pages -d dist`

Comment: thank you very much. You are right, changing build to dist works. I got message Published but when I tried the url in browser no content is showing.

Comment: I am not sure how to debug that really. You could try visiting the website after a few hours, try in incognito mode (without cache & cookies etc.), or try and see where GitHub pages show its errors of deployment maybe?